# jQuery script reset the form

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-events

I have page where I click on a link and change the content a of div with this code. I fill out that content with `page1.php` (it's a form with some dropdown lists).

When I try to click on a dropdown list it resets it. How can I stop resting my from when I try to select something from a drop down list?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){ 

    $('#page1').click(function(){
       pageUrl = 'page1.php';
       LoadingPages(pageUrl);
     })

     function LoadingPages(pageUrl){
       $('#content').load(pageUrl);
     }

     int = setInterval(function(){
       LoadingPages(pageUrl)
     },5000);
  });
</script>
```

HTML <sub>[(taken from comment's)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942062/jquery-script-reset-my-form#comment17541945_12942062)</sub>

```
<a href="#" id="page1">something</a> 
<div id="content">
```

Comment: you are using page onclick function.so definitely it will fire when you hits any where in page.

Comment: change your $("#page1") to something like $("#oneOfMyButtons").click.... (where #oneOfMyButtons is the id of a button that you want the user to click

Comment: What exactly is `#page1`? And what is `#content`? Maybe you could add some PHP/HTML code to your question, then it will be a lot more easier to answer to your question.

Comment: <a href="#" id="page1">something</a> and #content is <div id="content"> when i clik on link it change content of that div

Comment: Clicking on a link will redirect you in a non ajax way so you will lose the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suresh.g mentioned, using onClick on an element gets fired even if you click any inner element. The workaround is to set an action on the inner elements, you want to be clicked and stop their event propagation UPWARDS in the DOM tree. Thus it will fire the inner event and stop it from moving outwords, this preventing your #content onclick. Code is something like that:

```
$("#some_inner_element").bind('click', function(e){
    // Do your magic
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

});
```

Comment: @svenson you should also replace `href="#"` by real URI, pointing to real document (_same that AJAX would load_), like `href="page1.php"`, here is few but not only reasons for this: [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/a](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/a).

Comment: If it works, please mark my Answer as a solution. Glad I could help you :)